# Where best to place the prepositional phrase "en soi" {per se}?

Tags: ordre-des-mots

In a casual email, I just wrote:

> Habiter au Canada, ça me semble déjà être la conjoncture idéale **en soi** pour peaufiner ton français. Je parie que tu ne manques jamais d’occasions de parler français, et ce, tout en restant dans ton propre pays ! Et même si tu te retrouves bloqué sur un mot ou deux, il te suffit de te rabattre sur l’anglais. :)

This particular construction immediately sprang to mind, so this is probably how I would express the same idea orally, too. But the more I think about it, the more  I find myself wavering on what I think is the best position.

Question:

1) All possible positions to place the prepositional phrase "en soi"

2) The most natural-sounding position

Comment: Je ne comprends pas le sens de en soi dans cette phrase. Elle est tout aussi correcte sans et je n'ai pas l'impression qu'il rajoute une information.

Comment: Personnellement je ne l'emploierais dans cette phrase que pour modifier *être*, et donc le placerait après celui-ci. Pour renforcer *conjecture idéale* je préférerais *même*. Mais c'est peut-être une question d'opinion.

Comment: Dans ce cas le placer après être est effectivement la meilleure solution.

Comment: @user8171079 Hi. Pour moi, c'est comme "Living in Canada is an advantage ***in (and of) itself*** ou "Living in Canada ***per se*** is an advantage", une locution dont je ne me passe pas, ne serait-ce que pour mettre l'accent sur les effets ***importants*** apportés par le ***simple*** fait d'habiter au Canada.

Comment: @Laure Hi. Juste pour m'en assurer, tu préfères : "Habiter au Canada, ça me semble déjà être ***en soi*** la conjoncture idéale pour peaufiner ton français" ?

Comment: C'est ça.  Je ne dirais pas *La conjoncture idéale en soi* me parait bizarre, mais je dis bien c'est peut-être juste moi. Peut-être à cause de la présence d'*idéale* ? *En soi* modifie / renforce le mot à proximité.

Comment: @Laure Ja, *l'idéal* serait de ne pas séparer « idéale » de « pour ».

Comment: I'd prefer: "Habiter au Canada, ça me semble déjà être en soi la conjoncture idéale pour peaufiner ton français." But the formulation is bit heavy to my taste.

Comment: Je mettrais « situation » plutôt que « conjoncture ».

Comment: J'imagine que votre interlocuteur vous a répondu que ça dépend vraiment où puisque seulement 7,4% des anglophones hors Québec peuvent comprendre le français. On peut faire sa propre analyse : [1](http://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/national/201601/29/01-4945014-le-bilinguisme-canadien-progresse-grace-au-quebec.php), [2](http://www.statcan.gc.ca/pub/75-006-x/2013001/article/11795-fra.htm), [3](https://salic.uottawa.ca/?q=anglais_francais_taux). Merci !

Answer (score 1):

I could have placed it here:

> Habiter au Canada, **en soi**, ça me semble déjà être la conjoncture idéale pour...

Or here (most natural sounding position according to me):

> **En soi**, habiter au Canada, ça me semble déjà être la conjoncture idéale pour...

But honestly in this sentence I would not have necessarily used it. It sounds a bit too much, a bit like you really wanted to use it. Does not sound natural in my opinion.